# Special automorphism of the quaternionic structure

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

This question asks for the term 'special' automorphism' used in Encyclopedia of Mathematics' entry describing a [quaternionic structure](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Quaternionic_structure). As I have posted in other questions, a quaternionic structure on a $4n$-dimensional real vector space $V$ is a vector subspace (subalgebra) $Q\subset End(V)$ spanned by the identity and two anticommuting complex structures $J_1$ and $J_2$:

$$
Q=span_\mathbb R\{id_V,J_1,J_2,J_1J_2\} 
$$

(I usually ignore the identity and regard $Q$ as a 3-dimensional algebra, but since it is globally defined on any tangent bundle I think that does not matter actually).

Now, the Encyclopedia says:

> An automorphism $A$ of the vector space $V$ is called an automorphism of the quaternionic structure if the transformation $Ad A$ of the space of automorphisms induced by it preserves $Q$, that is, if $Ad A(Q)=AQA^{-1}=Q$. If, moreover, the identity automorphism is induced on $Q$, then $A$ is called a special automorphism of the quaternionic structure.

As a result, it says that the gruop of all special automorphisms of the quaternionic structure $Q$ is isomorphic to the general linear group $GL(n,\mathbb H)$ over the skew-field $\mathbb H$.
In differential geometry, I know this means that your two almost complex structures $J_1$ and $J_2$ are globally defined, something that may not happen in quaternionic manifolds (in the sense that the structure group reduces to $GL(n,\mathbb H)GL(1,\mathbb H)$). But it seems that in the linear case you can also have two different groups depending on if the identity automorphism is induced on $Q$ or not. And that is what I do not understand.

**Question.** What does ''the identity automorphism is induced on $Q$'' mean?

Comment: It means $A$ centralizes $Q$ (commutes with everything in it), not only normalizes it.  Also, you can't leave off the identity from $Q$ and get a 3-dimensional algebra.

Comment: @Kimball I see. Obviousl,  if $A$ commutes with every element in $Q$ it is going to preserve it. Thank you. And yes, I cannot leave the identity if I want $Q$ to be an algebra. Okey. If you want to post your comment as an answer I will accept it. If you think it is too short, you can add some technical details, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, I thought my comment was too short and I don't want to write more.  But you or anyone else is free to expand it into an answer.

Comment: @Kimball I might try, but it's not my field so that I' not sure I am enable.